# How to Change the Order of Integration for this Double Integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to change the limits of integration for this integral.

$ \int_0^4  \int_x^{\sqrt x} f(x,y) dydx$

If I plot it out, I see that the enclosed region where $0< x< 1, 0 < y < 1$ with the y=x being larger than $y = \sqrt x $ for values above $1$. This seems to tell me that the converted integral should be:

$\int_0^1 \int_{y^2}^y f(x,y) dydx $

But whenever I plug both into an integral calculator, I get different answers if I put in a random equation for $f(x,y)$, which tells me that isn't right. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am assuming it has to do with the region between $x = 1$ and $x = 4$, but I am not sure what to do with that, as it's not between the curves.

What am I missing?

Comment: Notice that you are ignoring the region where $x>1$. It doesn't show up on your plot because $x>\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Split $x$ bound to $[0,1]$ and $[1,4]$.

Comment: I'm not even sure your original integral makes sense. What does it mean to say $x$ to $\sqrt{x}$ after $x >1$?

Comment: @Randall: I think that's what I am having trouble with as well

Comment: It is definite integral, not need upper bound and lower bound be in order. Does make sense $\displaystyle \int_{\sin x}^{\cos x}f(x)\,dx$.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Split the integral into

$$ \int_0^1\int_\sqrt x^x f(x,y)\,dydx - \int_1^4 \int_x^\sqrt x f(x,y)\,dydx $$

The answer you had is equal to the first term. The second term will need to be further split into two terms after switching variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As it turns out, the TA had written the problem incorrectly (lol) and meant to make it far simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The second integral you wrote (the one with order changed) is only over the area of the graph enclosed between the $y=x$ straight line and the $y=\sqrt x$ curve. You're missing the area between these two and the $x=4$ straight line, for which you'll have to write another double integral and make the sum of both.